# How to get NFC tag id on Nexus using HTML5

Tags: android, html, nfc

I am building an HTML5 application which reads NFC tags. It is working on desktop PCs and I use a reader to read NFC tags. I want to run this app on Nexus and read the NFC from Nexus.... Does anyone know how to make Nexus read NFC tag and put the tag id on text box?

Answer (score 3):

We use this method in [our Android and iOS SDKs](http://flomio.com). For Android, you want to setup a simple app that registers for the NFC intent [`ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html) and then pushes the [`tag ID`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/Tag.html#getId()) to a variable. Then you can use a simple javascript injection method to get that data into a webview. Here's a sample, starting with an HTML page (index.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <input class="input-text" name="UUID" id="UUID" value="empty">
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Android Layout (activity_main.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
       android:id="@+id/webview" ></WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And java code (MainAcitivity.java):

```
package com.authorwjf.javascriptinjection;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final String URL = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
    private static final String tagUUID = "empty";
    private WebView mWebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                String javascript="javascript: document.getElementById('UUID').value="+tagUUID+";";
                view.loadUrl(javascript);
            }
        });

        IntentFilter mFilter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        BroadcastReceiver mScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String s = intent.getAction();
                if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(s)) {
                    Tag tag = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                    byte[] tagIDBytes = tag.getId();
                    String tagId = bytesToHexString(tagIDBytes);
                    MainActivity.this.PostToWebview(tagId);
                }
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(mScanReceiver, mFilter);
        refreshWebView();
    }

    public void PostToWebview(final String tagId) {
        tagUUID = tagId;
        refreshWebView();
    }

    private void refreshWebView() {
        mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
    }
}
```

I assembled this last piece in the editor without testing it so it might have some syntax errors. Overall though it should give you everything you need to get something working. Doing this on iOS is also possible using [a mobile NFC reader](http://flomio.com/shop/nfc-readers/). It's a bit more involved but [we can help get you going](http://flomio.com/forums/forum/ask-the-flomies/).